2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Proof Assistants's Moderator election #2 has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves:


They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Thanks to both of the new Moderators for their interest and commitment.
